# unable to access the dom element in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been trying to create a simple drag and drop component but I'm having problem selecting the div using `getElementById`. what am I doing wrong here? the error says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.

also the console log gives `null` instead of the div element.

```
<template>
    <div class="highlight" id="dragZone">
      <input
        v-model="inputText"
        placeholder="Write something..."
      />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import $auth from '@/services/auth';
import $utils from '@/services/utils';

const dropArea = document.getElementById('dragZone');
console.log(dropArea);

// Prevent default drag behaviors
function preventDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}

dropArea.addEventListener('dragenter', preventDefault, false);
dropArea.addEventListener('dragleave', preventDefault, false);
dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', preventDefault, false);
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', preventDefault, false);

// Handle dropped files
async function handleDrop(e) {
  const dt = e.dataTransfer;
  const files = dt.files;
  this.uploadingFile = await $utils.uploadFile(files, credentials);
}

dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

export default {
  props: {
    links: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data(){
   return{
      uploadingFile: null
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, how far did you read the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html)? It is noticeable that you do not follow the conventions of building a component. Ps. you are trying to access elements that have not even been rendered yet.

Answer (score 2):

In Vuejs you need to put your function inside the `method` object of your component.

And you also need to put the logic that needs to be run when the component is mounted inside the `mounted` object.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

```js
import $auth from "@/services/auth";
import $utils from "@/services/utils";

export default {
  props: {
    links: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      uploadingFile: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async handleDrop(e) {
      const dt = e.dataTransfer;
      const files = dt.files;
      this.uploadingFile = await $utils.uploadFile(files, credentials);
    },
    preventDefault(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Put logic that needs to be run when the component is mounted
    const dropArea = document.getElementById("dragZone");
    console.log(dropArea);

    // Prevent default drag behaviors

    dropArea.addEventListener("dragenter", this.preventDefault, false);
    dropArea.addEventListener("dragleave", this.preventDefault, false);
    dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", this.preventDefault, false);
    dropArea.addEventListener("drop", this.preventDefault, false);

    // Handle dropped files

    dropArea.addEventListener("drop", this.handleDrop, false);
  },
};
```

Also it is better to use `ref` if you want to access the dom.
[See Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

You can read the vuejs doc to better understand how Vuejs works.
https://vuejs.org/

Comment: it says handleDrop and preventDefaults are not defined

Comment: try with `this.handleDrop`